# I get this error in my script(Syntax error unexpected T_ELSE)

Tags: php, mysql, web, paypal-ipn

I have some problems with my script regarding the paypal IPN.
I use PHPDesigner 7 and it gives me a red error on line(88), I really tried to see if one of the braces is missing or if something is wrong but nothing seems wrong hoveren PHPDesigner shows me exactly at line 88(Syntax error unexpected T_ELSE).

Any help is appreciated Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
    <?php

// PHP 4.1

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

$File = "errorss.txt"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 $Data = "Entered the IPN script\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

 $Data = "Authentication Complete\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];

 $Data = "Iten number:".$item_number." ".$payment_status."\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 

if (!$fp) {


 $Data = "Error\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 

} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

 $Data = "Verified\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
    if($payment_status == "Completed")
    {

 $Data = "Completed\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 

require_once('./dbconnect.php');



$kkql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE w='$item_number'");



                if(mysql_num_rows($kkql) == 0)
                    {

                    exit(); 
                    } 

                                 mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET paid='1'");







                }
    }
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}

}
fclose ($fp);


} //This is also causing the error i think as it is red when it click on it, open and closed braces are displayed in green this one in red
 fclose($Handle); 
?>
```

Comment: Finding mis-matched brackets is much, much easier if you indent your code consistently.

Comment: you have an extra closing `}`

Comment: your `else if` don't have any parent `if` it is lying in the `else` case

Comment: Get a php aware IDE to edit your code it... they will point out where your missing brackets are

Answer (score 0):

Remove the closing bracket, `}`, on line 87 (85 or 86, if you prefer).

This is assuming you want the `else if` rather than an `if` on line 88, `else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this else does not fit with the rest of the code

```
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
```

I think you probably meant something like this

```
<?php

// PHP 4.1

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

$File = "errorss.txt"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
$Data = "Entered the IPN script\n"; 
fwrite($Handle, $Data); 

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$Data = "Authentication Complete\n"; 
fwrite($Handle, $Data); 

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];

$Data = "Iten number:".$item_number." ".$payment_status."\n"; 
fwrite($Handle, $Data); 

if (!$fp) {
 $Data = "Error\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
} else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            $Data = "Verified\n"; 
            fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
            if($payment_status == "Completed")
            {
                $Data = "Completed\n"; 
                fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
                require_once('./dbconnect.php');
                $kkql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE w='$item_number'");
                if(mysql_num_rows($kkql) == 0)
                {
                    exit(); 
                } 
                mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET paid='1'");
            }
        }
        if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
        }
    }
}
    fclose ($fp);
} //This is also causing the error i think as it is red when it click on it, open and closed braces are displayed in green this one in red
fclose($Handle); 
?>
```

If you indent your code nicely it makes mistakes like this very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments you have n extra `}` and your `elseif` condition is without the parent if condition try to put it after your `if`and remove the last closing `}`

```
 <?php

// PHP 4.1

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

$File = "errorss.txt"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
$Data = "Entered the IPN script\n";
fwrite($Handle, $Data);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$Data = "Authentication Complete\n";
fwrite($Handle, $Data);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];

$Data = "Iten number:".$item_number." ".$payment_status."\n";
fwrite($Handle, $Data);

if (!$fp) {


$Data = "Error\n";
fwrite($Handle, $Data);

} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

$Data = "Verified\n";
fwrite($Handle, $Data);
if($payment_status == "Completed")
{

$Data = "Completed\n";
fwrite($Handle, $Data);

require_once('./dbconnect.php');



$kkql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE w='$item_number'");



            if(mysql_num_rows($kkql) == 0)
                {

                exit();
                }

                             mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET paid='1'");







            }
}else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}
}



fclose ($fp);


} //This is also causing the error i think as it is red when it click on it, open and closed braces are displayed in green this one in red
fclose($Handle);
?>
```